# Rest API to get Subscription's Classic Administrators

Tags: rest, azure-rest-api

I use below rest API to get all other role assignments but i am not finding one for Classic administrators. Can someone

```
"https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{SubscriptionID}/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments?api-version=2018-09-01-preview"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. I was able to find the Rest API [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/authorization/classic-administrators/list)